# Displaying a progress wheel on main screen while connecting to internet [Android]

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, internet-connection

I want to display a progress bar which loads while connecting to internet in the logo screen. 
I am using below class to check the internet connection:

```
 public class AppStatus {
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }
}
```

The code of screen with progress bar is:

```
public class logo_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private AppStatus con = new AppStatus();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo_activity);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (con.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
                {
                    mProgressStatus += 10;
                   //user authentication in background.
                }
                else {
                    mProgressStatus +=10;
                   // Display an alert dialog box to connect to internet by launching into settings activity. 
                }

                // Update the progress bar
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

The problems i am facing is that the alert dialog box is not displaying and when i launch the activity into settings and exit without turning on the internet, the screen is stuck on loading screen only. 
Also can someone please write an asynctask method for it. I can't seem to get around it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the new thread that you have created still runs on the UI thread, so nothing is displayed because your UI is locked. you need to use an AssyncTask. [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/) is a tutorial.

Comment: So what do i do? I'll check out the tut on async task. Should i use async task for such task only?

Comment: @KavachChandra
tasks that take too long to run (e.g accessing internet) must not run on the UI thread, or you will see screen lags. instead you must run them asynchronously.
dealing with threads (concurency) is a bit complicated task, so android has provide preset classes such as AssyncTask and FutureTask to make concurrency simple. every time you asynchronicity you better use AssyncTask.

Comment: @KavachChandra plus accept my answer if it helped you.